# Exception when playing wave with WaveOutEvent of NAudio

Tags: c#, wpf, nullpointerexception, wav, naudio

In my WPF application, I want to play mp3 and wave files with WaveOutEvent from NAudio. It works fine with mp3s, but I get a NullReferenceException in NAudio.Core "The object reference has not been set to an object instance." when I run it with a wave-file. The exception occures after the player was started with _player.Play();

Here is my code:

```
using (AudioFileReader afr = new AudioFileReader(_filename))
{
  OffsetSampleProvider osp = new OffsetSampleProvider(afr);
  osp.SkipOver = currentCursorPosition;
  osp.Take = PlaybackDuration;

  WaveOutEvent player = new WaveOutEvent();
  player.Init(osp);
  player.Play();
}
```

Exception.Source = **NAudio.Core**
Exception.StackTrace =    **bei NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader.get_Position()**

Modul is **NAudio.Core.dll**, version **2.01.0.0**

Any idea what might be wrong and how to solve this?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

The `Play` method only begins playback. You're then disposing the `AudioFileReader` before it has finished playing the file.